# Transition on overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a left menu that slides in when the user clicks on the hamburger. Behind it is an overlay with the following SCSS:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: $glb-nav-80-opacity-white;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.left-menu {
    background: $glb-nav-dark-blue;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

    a:hover {
        color: $glb-nav-white;
    }
}
```

When people click on the hamburger menu, the overlay shows up abruptly. I need it to fade in. How can I do that using CSS?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="left-menu"></div>
```

When the user opens the page the `left-menu` has a left position of `-284px`. Then when people click on the hamburger icon, I add a class to the div that sets its left position to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a class, you can set the opacity using jQuery's .CSS
For example:

```
$(".overlay").css({opacity:50});
```

To reset it, use

```
$(".overlay").removeAttr("style");
```

Use CSS transitions as you did for the menu:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: $glb-nav-80-opacity-white;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css transitions as you did with the menu, ie:

```
.overlay {
  // other css 
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease;
     -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease;
       -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease;
          transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}
```

Or, if using SASS: `@include transition(opacity 500ms ease);`

Note, you can set the timing and style to be what you like, more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 0):

just add `transition` to the overlayed div

```css
div {
  /* -transition: 2 seconds- */
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: 2s;
  
}

div:hover {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>transition on hover</div>
```